# Why do my Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic D differ?

Tags: normal-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I did a ks test on excel through a youtube video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cltWQsmBg0k

In case I had done the excel wrongly I thought that I should check it with an online calculator of the ks test.
https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/kolmogorov/default.aspx

From the values I inputted, the online calculator and the excel spreadsheet, differ the ks test statistic D, by 0.007.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: It's not possible to figure out what you did from your post. Note that issues of implementation in code are often [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (see under *Programming*) unless the underlying issue needs statistical expertise (in this case, once you've defined the calculation, it's probably purely one of implementation). You will need to explain what it was you were trying to implement exactly (without relying purely on a link that might disappear at any time). Note that it's important to check the difference in cdf both just before and at each jump in the cdf.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is known to have a lot of inaccuracy in statistical testing. You are better off using other statistical software such as R or SAS.

Answer (score 0):

It could be almost anything.

- Maybe the Youtube was wrong.
- Maybe you misunderstood what it said.
- Maybe there was some coding error in Excel.
- Maybe the online calculator was wrong.
- Maybe there was a data entry error.

In any case, if you are going to be doing statistics, I would not rely on Excel or online calculators. And I'd be very careful about relying on a YouTube (only if it was an author who was known to me).  You should learn a statistical package such as R, SAS, Python stats, SPSS, Matlab and so on.

Or else, you should hire someone who knows at least one of those packages AND has training in statistics.